# Room automatically sorts on the basis of primary key in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, android-room

I have a data class like this

```
@Entity
data class Question(

        @field:SerializedName("question")
        var question: String? = null,

        @field:SerializedName("answers")
        var answers: ArrayList<String?>? = null,

        @field:SerializedName("id")
        @PrimaryKey
        var id: Int? = null
)
```

Then in DAO I have saving and getting methods like this

```
    @Dao
interface QnADao {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun saveQuestion(questions:Question)

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun saveAllQuestions(questions: List<Question?>?)


    @Query("SELECT * from Question")
    fun getAllQnA():List<Question>


}
```

I am saving a list of `Questions` and then later on retrieving them. So whenever I retrieve them I get the list sorted according to the `id` which is the primary key.

So if I am saving questions with `id:254`, `id:23`, `id:45` and `id:92` then I am getting it like this `id:23`, `id:45`, `id:92` and `id:254`

But I don't need a sorted list like that, I need to get the data as it was saved in the database. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Did you find any solution apart from adding another column as date?

Answer (score 4):

Try to use autoGenerate =  true for primary key so it will create PK number in sequence

See below lines

```
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
```

So that now your insert and retrive order will be same

Answer (score 2):

You can add a `Date` field to your Question entity

```
@field:SerializedName("date")
var date: Date? = null,
```

and order your entities by date

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM Question ORDER BY date DESC")
```