# Android Room error: The columns returned by the query does not have the fields even though they are annotated as non-null or primitive

Tags: java, android, android-room

So i wanna join my table using Room in Android Studio and this is my model class.

**Ibadah.java**

```
@Entity(tableName = "tibadah")
public class Ibadah implements Serializable {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    public int idIbadah;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "nama_ibadah")
    public String namaIbadah;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "deskripsi_ibadah")
    public String deskripsiIbadah;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "satuan_ibadah")
    public String satuanIbadah;

    public String getSatuanIbadah() {
        return satuanIbadah;
    }

    public void setSatuanIbadah(String satuanIbadah) {
        this.satuanIbadah = satuanIbadah;
    }

    public String getDeskripsiIbadah() {
        return deskripsiIbadah;
    }

    public void setDeskripsiIbadah(String deskripsiIbadah) {
        this.deskripsiIbadah = deskripsiIbadah;
    }

    public int getIdIbadah() {
        return idIbadah;
    }

    public void setIdIbadah(int idIbadah) {
        this.idIbadah = idIbadah;
    }

    public String getNamaIbadah() {
        return namaIbadah;
    }

    public void setNamaIbadah(String namaIbadah) {
        this.namaIbadah = namaIbadah;
    }

}
```

**SimpanTarget.java**

```
@Entity(tableName = "tabjoin")

public class SimpanTarget implements Serializable {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    public int idSimpan;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "id_ibajoin")
    public int idIbadahJoin;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "id_periode")
    public int idPeriode;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "id_target")
    public int idTarget;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "id_catat")
    public int idCatat;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "id_lapor")
    public int idLapor;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "id_satuan")
    public int idSatuan;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "nama_ibadah")
    public String namaIbadah;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "satuan_ibadah")
    public String satuanIbadah;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "target_ibadah")
    public boolean targetIbadah;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "catat_ibadah")
    public boolean catatIbadah;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "lapor_ibadah")
    public boolean laporIbadah;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "et_target")
    public String etTarget;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "et_capaian")
    public String etCapaian;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "status")
    public boolean status;

    public int getIdSimpan() {
        return idSimpan;
    }

    public void setIdSimpan(int idSimpan) {
        this.idSimpan = idSimpan;
    }

    public int getIdIbadahJoin() {
        return idIbadahJoin;
    }

    public void setIdIbadahJoin(int idIbadahJoin) {
        this.idIbadahJoin = idIbadahJoin;
    }

    public int getIdPeriode() {
        return idPeriode;
    }

    public void setIdPeriode(int idPeriode) {
        this.idPeriode = idPeriode;
    }

    public int getIdTarget() {
        return idTarget;
    }

    public void setIdTarget(int idTarget) {
        this.idTarget = idTarget;
    }

    public int getIdCatat() {
        return idCatat;
    }

    public void setIdCatat(int idCatat) {
        this.idCatat = idCatat;
    }

    public int getIdLapor() {
        return idLapor;
    }

    public void setIdLapor(int idLapor) {
        this.idLapor = idLapor;
    }

    public int getIdSatuan() {
        return idSatuan;
    }

    public void setIdSatuan(int idSatuan) {
        this.idSatuan = idSatuan;
    }

    public boolean isTargetIbadah() {
        return targetIbadah;
    }

    public void setTargetIbadah(boolean targetIbadah) {
        this.targetIbadah = targetIbadah;
    }

    public boolean isCatatIbadah() {
        return catatIbadah;
    }

    public void setCatatIbadah(boolean catatIbadah) {
        this.catatIbadah = catatIbadah;
    }

    public boolean isLaporIbadah() {
        return laporIbadah;
    }

    public void setLaporIbadah(boolean laporIbadah) {
        this.laporIbadah = laporIbadah;
    }

    public String getEtTarget() {
        return etTarget;
    }

    public void setEtTarget(String etTarget) {
        this.etTarget = etTarget;
    }

    public String getEtCapaian() {
        return etCapaian;
    }

    public void setEtCapaian(String etCapaian) {
        this.etCapaian = etCapaian;
    }

    public boolean isStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(boolean status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getNamaIbadah() {
        return namaIbadah;
    }

    public void setNamaIbadah(String namaIbadah) {
        this.namaIbadah = namaIbadah;
    }

    public String getSatuanIbadah() {
        return satuanIbadah;
    }

    public void setSatuanIbadah(String satuanIbadah) {
        this.satuanIbadah = satuanIbadah;
    }
}
```

**IbadahDAO.java**

```
@Dao
public interface IbadahDAO {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    long insertIbadah (Ibadah ibadah);

    @Update
    int updateIbadah (Ibadah ibadah);

    @Delete
    int deleteIbadah (Ibadah ibadah);

    @Insert (onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    long insertTarget (Ibadah ibadah);

    @Insert (onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    long insertCapai (Ibadah ibadah);

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    long insertNamaTarget (NamaTarget namaTarget);

    @Update
    int updateNamaTarget (NamaTarget namaTarget);

    @Delete
    int deleteNamaTarget (NamaTarget namaTarget);

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    long insertIbadah (NamaTarget namaTarget);

    @Update
    int updateIbadah (NamaTarget namaTarget);

    @Insert (onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    long insertTarget (NamaTarget namaTarget);

    @Insert (onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    long insertCapai (NamaTarget namaTarget);

    @Insert (onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    long insertDataTarget (SimpanTarget simpanTarget);

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    long insertIbadah (SimpanTarget simpanTarget);

    @Update
    int updateIbadah (SimpanTarget simpanTarget);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM ttarget WHERE nama_target = nama_target")
    NamaTarget[] selectAllNamaTargets();

    @Query("SELECT * FROM tibadah")
    Ibadah[] selectAllStatus();

    @Query("SELECT * FROM tibadah")
    Ibadah[] selectAllIbadahs();

    @Query("SELECT * FROM tibadah WHERE idIbadah = :id LIMIT 1")
    Ibadah selectIbadahDetail(int id);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM ttarget WHERE idTarget = :id LIMIT 1")
    NamaTarget selectPeriodeDetail(int id);

    @SuppressWarnings(RoomWarnings.CURSOR_MISMATCH)
    @Query("SELECT tabjoin.idSimpan, tibadah.nama_ibadah " +
            "FROM tabjoin, tibadah " +
            "WHERE tabjoin.id_ibajoin = tibadah.nama_ibadah ")
    SimpanTarget[] selectAllIbadahJoin();
}
```

So my question is when i wanna join that table using this code

> @Query("SELECT tabjoin.idSimpan, tibadah.nama_ibadah " +
>               "FROM tabjoin, tibadah " +
>               "WHERE tabjoin.id_ibadah = tibadah.nama_ibadah ")
>
> SimpanTarget[] selectAllIbadahJoin();

And then it show this error

> **error: The columns returned by the query does not have the fields**
>   [idIbadah,idPeriode,idTarget,idCatat,idLapor,idSatuan,targetIbadah,catatIbadah,laporIbadah,status]
>   in skripsi.com.ggr.managementibadah.model.SimpanTarget
>   **even though they are annotated as non-null or primitive.**
>
> **Columns returned by the query: [idSimpan,nama_ibadah]**

I feel that error is shown because i don't relate my table? Is that true? And if not how to solve that error? I hope you can help me.
Thank you very much and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: SimpanTarget[] selectAllIbadahJoin(); post this class code

Comment: Visit this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55155337/room-automatically-sorts-on-the-basis-of-primary-key-in-android/55155477#55155477 may help

Comment: Okay, i'll post class code

Comment: In my model class, i'm always using @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)

Answer (score 10):

It has nothing to do with relations. The error message basically says: in your query you are only selecting `tabjoin.idSimpan`, and `tibadah.nama_ibadah`; and you are trying to return an array of type `SimpanTarget`. Those two fields are not enough to create a `SimpanTarget` instance. You should be selecting the entire set of fields instead. For example: `SELECT tabjoin.*`