# All queries in RoomDatabase return: The columns returned by the query does not have the fields

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

I have a problem with queries in RoomDatabase. I have a different queries and everything works good when I use `SELECT` statement with `*`. When I want to choose only **name_product** or **amount** it gives an error:

```
error: The columns returned by the query does not have the fields [id,amount,to_shop,cat_food,cat_package] in com.example.myapp.PojoClass even though they are annotated as non-null or primitive. Columns returned by the query: [name_product,amount]
 LiveData<List<Items>> getItemNameAndAmount(int category);
```

One of my query:

```
@Query("SELECT name_product, amount FROM Table WHERE to_shop = 1 AND food_type = :category")
 LiveData<List<Item_get>> getCategoryThingsToBuy(int category);
```

Problem is similar with this:
[Android Room error: The columns returned by the query does not have the fields even though they are annotated as non-null or primitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55215304/android-room-error-the-columns-returned-by-the-query-does-not-have-the-fields-e)
But I don't understand why this won't compile. Can somebody tell me?
In my PojoClass I have got a lot of different fields but only categories above are return as an error.
Why Android Studio doesn't throw me all of my Pojo fields as error? Not Only those above.
It throws errors in all queries statements not in one or two.
If it matter I have a empty constructor in my PojoClass.

**EDIT:**
My PojoClass

```
@Entity(tableName = "Table", indices = @Index(value = {"name_product"}, unique = true))

public class Item_get implements Parcelable {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    public int id;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "name_product")
    protected String name_product;

    private String date_buy;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "amount")
    private int amount;
    private Double price;
    private Double value;
    protected String date_exp;
    protected String buy_place;
    private String date_buy2;
    private String buy_place2;
    private Double price2;
    private String date_buy3;
    private String buy_place3;
    private Double price3;
    private int to_shop;
    private int amount_toShop;
    protected String actual_date;
    private int cat_food;
    protected int cat_package;
    private int cat_packageToShop;


    @TypeConverters(CategoriesConverter.class)
    public Food_type food_type;

    protected Item_get(Parcel in) {
        id = in.readInt();
        name_product = in.readString();
        date_buy = in.readString();
        amount = in.readInt();
        if (in.readByte() == 0) {
            price = null;
        } else {
            price = in.readDouble();
        }
        if (in.readByte() == 0) {
            value = null;
        } else {
            value = in.readDouble();
        }
        date_exp = in.readString();
        buy_place = in.readString();
        date_buy2 = in.readString();
        buy_place2 = in.readString();
        if (in.readByte() == 0) {
            price2 = null;
        } else {
            price2 = in.readDouble();
        }
        date_buy3 = in.readString();
        buy_place3 = in.readString();
        if (in.readByte() == 0) {
            price3 = null;
        } else {
            price3 = in.readDouble();
        }
        to_shop = in.readInt();
        actual_date = in.readString();
        cat_food = in.readInt();
        cat_package = in.readInt();
        amount_toShop = in.readInt();
        cat_packageToShop = in.readInt();

    }

    public static final Creator<Item_get> CREATOR = new Creator<Item_get>() {
        @Override
        public Item_get createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Item_get(in);
        }

        @Override
        public Item_get[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Item_get[size];
        }
    };

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeInt(id);
        dest.writeString(name_product);
        dest.writeString(date_buy);
        dest.writeInt(amount);
        if (price == null) {
            dest.writeByte((byte) 0);
        } else {
            dest.writeByte((byte) 1);
            dest.writeDouble(price);
        }
        if (value == null) {
            dest.writeByte((byte) 0);
        } else {
            dest.writeByte((byte) 1);
            dest.writeDouble(value);
        }
        dest.writeString(date_exp);
        dest.writeString(buy_place);
        dest.writeString(date_buy2);
        dest.writeString(buy_place2);
        if (price2 == null) {
            dest.writeByte((byte) 0);
        } else {
            dest.writeByte((byte) 1);
            dest.writeDouble(price2);
        }
        dest.writeString(date_buy3);
        dest.writeString(buy_place3);
        if (price3 == null) {
            dest.writeByte((byte) 0);
        } else {
            dest.writeByte((byte) 1);
            dest.writeDouble(price3);
        }
        dest.writeInt(to_shop);
        dest.writeString(actual_date);
        dest.writeInt(cat_food);
        dest.writeInt(cat_package);
        dest.writeInt(amount_toShop);
        dest.writeInt(cat_packageToShop);
    }

    public enum Food_type{
        SWEETS(1),
        VEGETABLES_FRUITS(2),
        DRINKS(3),
        OTHER(4);
        private int code;
        Food_type(int code){
            this.code = code;
        }
        public int getCode(){
            return code;
        }
    }

    @TypeConverters(PackageTypeConverter.class)
    public Package_type package_type;


    public enum Package_type{
        PACKAGE_BOX(1),
        PIECE(2),
        OTHER_PACK(3);
        private int code;
        Package_type(int code){
            this.code = code;
        }
        public int getCode(){
            return code;
        }
    }
    public Item_get(){

    }
```

To short of my code I didn't paste all constructors beacuse I use different in each class.
Also I skipped getters and setters. If it is necessarily I will paste it.

Comment: can you share `Item_get` table

Comment: You mean place where I have my Entity?

Comment: Ok. I edited the code.